# How to save data in services if user refreshed page or close the tab in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I have an Angular Application (single page application). I have stored my data in Service.ts but if user refresh the browser or close the tab then I lost my data and can't retrieve it.

If i store data in localStorage then it is not secure untill i encrypt my data.

Would you please help me How can i store my daya which should not lose on refresh or tab close.

If answer is LocalStorage then please guide me How can i encrypt my data before to store and decrypt while read it from localStorage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: LocalStorage and cookies are made for persisting the data

Comment: Implement a server backend. There is no easy way to perform secure client-side encryption of data.

Comment: can share some screenshot what happening and what backend are you  using

Comment: If you need the data to persist when tab close, localStorage is the only choice. since you are using angular, you can easily use any npm package (e.g. bcrypt) to encrypt the data and decrypt when reading. The data is saved in string format in localStorage, so you may need to do `JSON.stringify(obj)` and `JSON.parse(obj)` while  saving/reading the data.

Comment: @SachinGupta BCrypt doesn't encrypt. It hashes. And if it were to encrypt: there is generally no point in performing client-side encryption, because the encryption/decryption key needs to  be present on the client as well. (Yes, I'm aware there are exceptions with custom browser extensions, secure devices, and so on.)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen. My bad, just wanted to give an example for npm package.  Can use `jsonwebtoken`instead

Comment: @SachinGupta `jsonwebtoken` is equally ill-suited for the task at hand. Aside from  solutions that rely on secure hardware, there is no safe way to encrypt data on the client.

Comment: I have to store in LocalStorage but can't store without encrytion. Please suggest me encryption compiler

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lz-string it works for me on angular 7. What this do it will make it unreadable and compress it and combine this with a base64 for encryption. This will make sure that your localstorage is not getting to big cause it's limited for every browser I think 10mb is the max.